# Put Items using Json File in AWS DynamoDB using AWS CLI

Tags: json, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda, aws-cli

While putting below JSON in dynamo DB using AWS CLI with below command:

```
aws dynamodb put-item --table-name ScreenList --item file://tableName.json
```

I am getting Parameter validation failed Exception.I have gone rigorously through AWS docs but failed to find example to insert a complicated json.Every small help is welcome.

The updated Json :

```
{
  "itemName": {
    "S": "SCREEN_LIST"
  },
  "productName": {
    "S": "P2P_MOBITEL"
  },
  "screenList": {
    "L": [
      {
        "menu": {
          "L": [
            {
              "M": {
                "menuId": {
                  "N": "1"
                },
                "menuText": {
                  "S": "ENG_HEADING"
                },
                "menuType": {
                  "S": "Dynamic"
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "M": {
          "screenFooter": {
            "S": "F_LANGUAGE_CHANGE"
          },
          "screenHeader": {
            "S": "H_LANGUAGE_CHANGE"
          },
          "screenId": {
            "S": "LANGUAGE_CHANGE"
          },
          "screenType": {
            "S": ""
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the answer, please take a look.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems that you are defining complex types incorrectly. According to [AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_AttributeValue.html) you should define a list like this:

```
"L": ["Cookies", "Coffee", 3.14159]
```

and a map should be defined like this:

```
"M": {"Name": {"S": "Joe"}, "Age": {"N": "35"}}
```

which means that a `menu` map should be defined like this:

```
"menu": { 
  "L": [
    {
      "M": {
        "menuId": {"N" :"1"},
        "menuText": {"S" :"PACKS_SCREEN"},
        "menuType": {"S" :"Dynamic"}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Notice the "M" and "L" attributes.

You should change the rest of your JSON in a similar fashion.

You can find full JSON definition [here in the Options section](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/put-item.html).

**UPDATE**

Now your list definition is incorrect. You have:

```
   "screenList":{  
      "L":[  
         {  
            "menu":{ ... },
            "M":{ ... }
         }
      ]
   }
```

While it should be:

```
   "screenList":{  
      "L":[  
         {  
            "M":{ ... }   
         },
         {  
            "M":{ ... }   
         },
      ]
   }
```

Comment: Again it says  was parameter validation Exception...it says unknown parameter "menu".It should be must be one of :S,N,B,M,L.

Comment: I am not sure if this is an issue with StackOverflow or with your JSON, but it does not pass JSON validation. Try to ensure that this is valid JSON first (e.g. you can use an online formatter: https://jsonformatter.org/)

Comment: Also, could you update JSON in your question? It's hard to read it in the comment section.

Comment: It worked , but here I need name of map.The entries are added in the table along with the "L","M".I want to replace 2 maps  "M","M" in List "L " with some name so that i can retrieve easily and my table becomes readable.

Comment: You can have item names in a list. You can either make "screenList" a map (I guess it would be "screenMap" then), or you can store a nested map in a list something like [{"menu": {}, "else": {}}]. Mind that you need to convert this into DynamoDB format.